# http://stackoverflow.com/q/5843110/529215

Tags: discussion, linux

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5843110/529215

sorry guys i dont know how to migrated from the stack over flow site please refer the url

thanks in advance

Comment: Flag it to moderator for migrating the question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/move-questions-between-stack-overflow-sites

Comment: This is as off topic here as it was on SF.